# cocoon building resources after form is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have a form for bills. Once open I choose a vendor to show the list of open purchase orders for the vendor. Selecting the purchase order should take all the items that were ordered in the purchase order and show them as line items in the bill.

How can this be achieved when the form is already rendered and I already see nested attributes and the link to add more or remove etc on the form?

My current implementation is the simple nested resource using cocoon.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@bill) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :vendor_id, as: :select do %>
      <%= f.grouped_collection_select :vendor_id, Warehouse.ordered, :vendors, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div id="items">
    <div id="ingredient_purchase" class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :warehouse_ingredient_purchase_logs do |warehouse_ingredient_purchase_log| %>
        <%= render 'warehouse_ingredient_purchase_log_fields', :f => warehouse_ingredient_purchase_log %>
        <% end #f.simple_fields_for %>
        <div class="links">
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add More', f, :warehouse_ingredient_purchase_logs %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end #simple_form_for(@bill) do |f| %>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Purchase Orders</h4>
    <div class="purchase_orders_data"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you combine different purchase orders in one bill? Always only one vendor, right?

Comment: For now looking for one purchase order per bill. Maybe enhance it later for multiple purchase orders. And of course one vendor per bill.

Comment: I would first collect the parameters: the vendor, and one or more purchase orders, and use that data to build the bill and then show it. How you do this practically (using html or ajax/xhr) is up to you but effectively wait to build the bill-form when you know how it should be built. Is that clear?

Comment: How can I collect the parameters first when I am already on the bill creation screen. Not sure about that. My current flow is like this.

I come to new bill screen, choose a vendor, a modal opens with all the vendor's open purchase orders, and I can select the purchase order I want to use. 

Now what I want to happen is once I select the purchase order, the line items of that purchase order should become the line items of the new bill.

My question is how to append the 3 or 4 or 5 line items to the bill screen?

Comment: Options: 1) open bill creation screen, show list of vendors, show modal, then post and create the bill and then redirect to edit (easy but the bill is already created and maybe you do not want that), 2) open bill creation screen, the controller has no params so: show list of vendors, show modal, and then do get bill creation screen again but with the given parameters (vendor + bill) and show correct form for creating a new bill; 3) open bill creation, show list of vendors, open modal, when selected do ajax/xhr call to build form and only then render it and proceed.

Comment: If you could post your solution, I will accept it as the right answer. Your assistance helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, instead of first rendering a form and then trying to amend it using javascript, 
I would first collect the parameters: the vendor, and one or more purchase orders, and use that data to build the bill and then show it.

How you do this practically (using html or ajax/xhr) is up to you but effectively wait to build the bill-form when you know how it should be built.

Possible approaches:

- open bill creation screen, show list of vendors, show modal, then post and create the bill and then redirect to edit (easy but the bill is already created and maybe you do not want that),
- open bill creation screen, the controller has no params so: show list of vendors, show modal, and then do get bill creation screen again but with the given parameters (vendor + bill) and show correct form for creating a new bill;
- open bill creation, show list of vendors, open modal, when selected do ajax/xhr call to build form and only then render it and proceed.

This is pretty generic but might help to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can accomplish this with [`ajax`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns)

when you select one of those items you need to perform an asynchronous call to the backend server. The page does not refresh with asynchronous call.

You can trigger this with [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) or [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper, then configure the routing to trigger your action (or just use model object automatically generate routes) and in your action fetch those vendor bills:

```
def action
   @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
   @bills = @vendor.bills
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
end
```

in your js file `action.js.erb` you can write the js logic to modify your form

also the vendor bill can be included in a partial `_object.html.erb` and `action.js.erb` can append that partial to the page with

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @object) %>").appendTo("#yourHtmlId");
```

Comment: Looks promising let me see if i can accomplish this. JS is not my strength :(

Comment: @QaiserWali JS it's great... and it will be easy for you to understand. Just remember to extensively read the documentation offered, that will allow you to solve any issue you have.